# Number.isInteger method and Node.js version

Tags: node.js

Using Node.js 4.5.0 I got the expected behaviour

```
> console.log(Number.isInteger(42))
true
```

but using Node.js 0.10.36 I got the error

```
> console.log(Number.isInteger(42))
TypeError: Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'isInteger'
```

How I know which is the *minimal* version of Node.js required for using the
`Number.isInteger` method?

I couldn't find any related information after grepping Node.js CHANGELOG [files](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/doc/changelogs).

Edit 1: [node.green](http://node.green/) shows that the method is supported from Node.js 0.12.16.

Edit 2: Neither could I find any related information in V8 [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/ChangeLog).

Comment: I added the information shown by [node.greeen](http://node.green/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As they recommend to look after in their [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#which-features-ship-with-which-node-js-version-by-default), `Number.isInteger` is [supported](http://node.green/#Number-properties) in version 0.12.16.  Though that's  not the minimum version, which might be 0.12.3 which uses the same [v8 engine version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

Edit #1: In this [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/127c660eabffe445ba2aa4ae14e746c514011482/ChangeLog) V8 3.24.11 was released, but Node.js only made use of V8 3.25.30.0 in [version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) 0.11.13. Furthermore, I made some tests (in Xubuntu 16.04):

**Node.js v0.11.13** (V8 3.25.30.0)

```
> Number.isInteger(42)
true
```

**Node.js v0.11.12** (V8 3.22.24.19)

```
> Number.isInteger(42)
TypeError: Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'isInteger'
    at repl:1:8
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:130:27)
    at bound (domain.js:255:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:268:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:277:12)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:806:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:101:10)
```

Notice that in Node.js v0.11.12, V8 3.22.24.19 is lower than 3.24.11 which is when they [added](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5490#c1) `Number.isInteger`. So, in conclusion, **Node.js v0.11.13** is the *minimal* version that has method 'isInteger'.

Comment: Note that the version of V8 supported by 0.12.0, 0.12.1 and 0.12.2 is greater than the version supported by 0.12.3.

Answer (score 1):

`Number.isInteger()` was added in V8 3.26.30 (see [this](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/127c660eabffe445ba2aa4ae14e746c514011482) commit pointed out [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5490)), so the minimal version of Node.js supporting this method is [0.12.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

Answer (score 0):

`Number.isInteger()` is [defined in ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number.isinteger); it requires a Node version that implements ES6.